# Not able to send json response from shouldInterceptLoadRequest

Tags: android, html

In my application, I want to intercept all network calls and want to handle them in native android application. I am facing issue in returning json response to html. It is giving error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Please find below my html:
    
    
        
            
            
            function myCall() {

```
            var request = $.ajax({
                url: "http://ip.jsontest.com/",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            });
            request.done(function(msg) {
                alert("Response: " + msg);

            });

            request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
            });
        }
    </script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>My jQuery Ajax test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #mybox {
         width: 300px;
         height: 250px;
         border: 1px solid #999;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    The following div will be updated after the call:<br />
    <div id="mybox"></div>
    <input type="button" value="Update" onclick="myCall()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my shouldInterceptLoadRequest method:

```
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptLoadRequest(WebView, String url) {
    if(url.startsWith("http://ip")){
        SNAPIRequestModel apiModel = new SNAPIRequestModel(url);
        apiModel.setRequestType(SNConstants.GET_REQUEST);
        apiModel.setMethodCallType(SNConstants.SYNCHRONOUS_CALL);

        //invoke the core data manager to get the data from network
        Object response =  ... //fetching response

        if(response!=null) {
            try {
                JSONObject data = ((JSONObject) response);
                System.out.print(data.toString());
                InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
                return new WebResourceResponse("application/json;", "UTF-8", stream);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {

            }
        }
    }
    return super.shouldInterceptLoadRequest(view, url);
}
```

Comment: In place of hitting url http://url from ajax, use java code to fetch json from url and then use in html page because ajax cannot acces cross domain cause of security....or use cross-origin resource sharing

Comment: I am fetching json in native only. I am not sure where should I write url in the html which will be intercept in the native, so I tried with ajax

Comment: in your java class you have json put that json in request parameter and in your ajax of html fetch data.

Comment: Sorry Rah, I didn't get it. I have created an android native application in which we are displaying UI using htmls in webview. For n/w calls, we are intercepting using shouldInterceptLoadRequest and then fetching data using HttpClient and return it from the shouldInterceptLoadRequest.